# How to update corresponding copy of a global variable based on a condition in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

So I have 3 global variables in a view controller (let's call them A,B,C) that I need to update to retain the state of filter selection as the app navigates to and away from this view controller. I am sharing a filter view controller between 2 other view controllers since they both reference it. However, they need to utilize their own set of the 3 global variables in order to ensure the state of those variables gets saved and cleared based on different criteria.

Basically, I have 2 similar pages with the same advanced filter UI. When the filters are applied, I save the state onto 3 of these variables in order to restore their state in the UI when they are invoked again. However, VC1's filter state remains saved during the entire app lifecycle while VC2's filter state is only saved while the user is on that page. If the user navigates away, VC2's filter selection state gets reset. Given that I have to manage 2 copies of the global variables for both, what is the most optimal approach to saving the separate states within the filterVC?

As of right now, I'm going with the basic if-condition check to see which page the filters are referenced from to determine which version of the global variables to read/write. Every time these global variables are referenced (13 instances), I do an if-condition screen check to read or write from the corresponding VC's global variable. Do note that the filter UI is a standalone full-screen page with its own VC that gets invoked on a button click, so in order to restore the state of VC2's selections in filterVC when the filter UI is dismissed and re-opened, I have to establish that state in a global variable so it can be accessed in filterVC. However, this approach doesn't seem like the most optimal even though it works, so I'm looking for a better way to go about it.

For simplicity, please see below:

> 2 view controllers: VC1, VC2
>
> Separate copies of 3 global variables used by VC1, VC2: A,B,C
>
> 1 shared filter UI view controller: filterVC

Comment: Your structure is flawed.  You should not have viewControllers that own state.  I'd recommend you move to the coordinator pattern.  Here is an intro to it:  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps

Comment: @HalR These VCs don't own state in their class files. The state is stored globally throughout the app codebase and can be referenced by any VC right now. The coordinator pattern seems to standardize navigation between VCs, which I don't see how it relates to my needs here